# Count records month and days wise depending on user subscription

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the number of subscribers for a particular month and day and print it in a tabular format. I have 3 tables (registration, registration_session and commodity) and want to count numbers of records month and day wise based on registration from commodity table with update date limit of 30 days. I have given the solution and it's working fine but it's taking lot of time to print the final result.

Edited:
My Plan is to print the total number of SMS/Voice Call detail for entire year that has to be send. But don't count the records that is older then 30 days. Please check my php code given below, you may understand what i am trying to do. It's working but the problem is, it's very slow. It's is take almost an hour to complete the task.

Final Result:

```
          Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
January    17333  15455   15368     16348    14827  15054    14637
February   17332  15481   15400     16351    14824  15059    14613
March      17125  15689   15721     16393    14807  14938    14479
April      18542  17426   17485     17941    16414  16427    15972
May        15824  14870   15044     15441    14311  14485    13861
June       15186  14138   14360     14769    13643  13798    13195
July       13496  12602   12837     13163    12168  12228    11669
August     13305  12333   12570     12891    11913  11974    11422
September  13286  12371   12649     12913    11898  11927    11553
October    12893  11773   11912     12390    11407  11516    11097
November   13563  12415   12516     13042    12028  12173    11764
December   13849  12172   12274     13041    11797  12119    11613
```

**My question is that, how to make it faster?**

**My Tables:**
registration

```
id  mobile      name        day             state   language    status
1   1234566532  ishtiyaq    'SUN:MON'       up      en          1
2   2313443454  sandeep     'MON:TUE'       up      en          1
3   7436343422  shiv        'MON:TUE:WED'   up      en          1
```

registration_session

```
id  reg_id  session         com             distt               status
1   1       'JAN:FEB'       com1:com2:com3  dist1:dist2:dist3   1
2   1       'DEC:JAN:FEB'   com1:com2       dist1:dist2         1
3   2       'APR:MAY:JUN'   com4:com6       dist4:dist8         1
```

commodity

```
id  state   distt   com     price   date_updated
1   up      distt1  com1    200     2015-04-23
2   up      distt2  com2    420     2015-12-17
3   up      distt4  com3    340     2015-10-16
4   up      distt1  com2    560     2015-09-13
5   up      distt4  com4    320     2015-11-01
6   mp      distt5  com2    322     2015-10-01
7   dl      distt7  com5    120     2015-12-11
```

Result:

```
|--------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|        |  Sunday       |  Monday       |  Tuesday      |  Wednesday    |  Thursday     |  Friday       |  Saturday     |
|--------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|January |  9876-14150   |  8533-12026   |  8491-11991   |  9136-13027   |  8196-11581   |  8404-12015   |  8244-11748   |
|--------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|Febury  |  9845-13450   |  8521-54026   |  5441-13491   |  1136-13217   |  7196-16531   |  8704-12613   |  2244-14748   |
|--------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
......
```

My Solution:

```
$arr_months = array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC');
$arr_days = array('SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT');

foreach ($arr_months as $month) {
    foreach ($arr_days as $day) {
        $total_msg = 0;
        $total_rec = 0;

        $sql1 = "SELECT registration.mobile,
                  registration.id,
                  registration.state,
                  registration.language,
                  registration_session.com,
                  registration_session.distt
             FROM registration_session
                 INNER JOIN registration
                     ON registration_session.reg_id = registration.id
                 WHERE registration_session.session LIKE '%" . $month . "%'
                     AND registration.status = 1
                     AND registration.language = 'en'
                     AND registration.day LIKE '%" . $day . "%'
                 ORDER BY registration.mobile";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            $state = $row1['state'];
            $commodity = explode(':', $row1['commodity']);
            $distt = explode(':', $row1['distt']);
            $count = count($commodity);

            $found = false;
            while ($count > 0) {
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM commodity
                            WHERE date_updated BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()
                            AND state = '".$state."'
                            AND distt = '".$distt[$count - 1]."'
                            AND cv_commodity = '".$commodity[$count - 1]."'";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                    $total_msg++;
                    $found = true;
                }
                $count--;
            }
            if ($found == true) {
                $total_rec++;
            }
        }
    }
}



--
-- Table structure for table `commodity`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `commodity` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `distt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `com` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Create Table Statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mobile` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration_session` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reg_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `com` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `distt` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `reg_id` (`reg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `commodity` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `distt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `com` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` statements & an `EXPLAIN PLAN` of the queries?

Comment: LIKE '%,,,' prevents the use of an index. If you can rewrite that as a range query, it will be much faster

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your loops correctly, this script is making a whole lot of calls to the DB.  The first query is weekdays * months (84 queries), and then it's all possible combinations of state, commodity, and distt for each of those 84 loops.

I recommend taking all results for both queries once and then looping through the records in PHP to form your results by Month, Day and by State, Commodity, and Distt.

I'd also rollup your queries if you don't need that level of grain.  In example on the first one:

```
SELECT 
    registration.day,
    registration.mobile,
    registration.id,
    registration.state,
    registration.language,
    registration_session.com,
    registration_session.session,
    registration_session.distt,
    COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM 
    registration_session
INNER JOIN 
    registration ON registration_session.reg_id = registration.id
WHERE 
    AND registration.status = 1
    AND registration.language = 'en'
GROUP BY
    registration.day,
    registration.mobile,
    registration.id,
    registration.state,
    registration.language,
    registration_session.com,
    registration_session.session,
    registration_session.distt
```

And the commodity one:

```
SELECT 
    state,
    distt,
    cv_commodity,
    COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM 
    commodity
WHERE 
    date_updated BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()
GROUP BY
    state,
    distt,
    cv_commodity
```

Then do your PHP loops through the results:

```
$arr_months = array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC');
$arr_days = array('SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT');

foreach ($arr_months as $month) {
    foreach ($arr_days as $day) {
        $total_msg = 0;
        $total_rec = 0;

    foreach ($result1 AS $row1) {
        if (strpos($row1['session'],$month) !== false AND strpos($row1['day'],$day) !== false){
            $state = $row1['state'];
            $commodity = explode(':', $row1['com']);
            $distt = explode(':', $row1['distt']);
            #$count = number of commodities * number of records in db for this row
            $count = count($commodity) * $row1['cnt']; 

            #Check if State/Commodity exist in $result2 using the same strpos method above
            #Store aggregates for each month/day in a new array to display results
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the approach I would take to optimize performance by reducing the number of DB queries, roll-up the results so less records need to be loaded into memory up front, and then loop through to get my results.

Comment: this method is also taking long time to complete the task.

Comment: Can you post the results of EXPLAIN on both of those queries?  And if you have it, how long do they currently take to run?

Comment: You might try not rolling up the data if query performance suffered but continue with the single pass and then loop approach.  Wouldn't hurt to add an index on each column in your WHERE clauses to see how that improves performance as well (IE, status, and language for the first query, date_updated for the second query.